# Path to visual studio reference gets lost

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I organize my projects in the following way:

```
LocalThirdPartyLibraries\
    ThirdPartyLibraryA\A.dll
    ThirdPartyLibraryB\B.dll
    ...
Sources\
    ProjectX
    ProjectY
    ...
```

In my projects I reference the local third party libraries and set the *copy local* property to true.
When I understand it correctly, I need to do this because I don't register them in the GAC.

From time to time, the paths for my local references get lost for some of my projects (not all) 
and instead of pointing to
**LocalThirdPartyLibraries\LibraryA** directory, they point to the bin 
folder of the project. It is difficult to find out, for what reason this happens, because
the project continues to compile until I clean the bin folder.

What can I do, to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Are you saying that the Clean command breaks your build?

Comment: When exactly does this happen, for example the first time you Clean your project after adding the references from their respective `LocalLibraries` paths? If you use source control, you can see which action causes a hintpath change in your project's `.csproj` file, which could probably be what this is.

Comment: Normally I would expect this behavior if you somehow lost your dll in libraryA. Visual studio then would find reference in bin. But when that is happen, go to `proj` file and look, where reference pointed to

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I did not formulate it clear, I meant, that when I clean the bin folders, then I cannot compile any more.

Comment: I think I know your issue. You probably don't have right build order if there are multiple projects in solution. So, when you clean the build, it fails because one project relies on another. And I hope you don't have circular dependencies. Fix your build order

Comment: @T.S.: Yes I have multiple projects. The strange thing is also that the references don't get lost for all projects. When I check the project dependencies with resharper, I can see that I have no circular dependencies. How can I easily fix the build order?

Comment: @StefanG Build order is somewhere on solution menu

Comment: @HansPassant I have not used project references for many years now and everything is OK. The pattern that has been used [and in more than one company] is build to bin, which is also a "library bin". In other words, build to the same folder from where references come.

Comment: I updated my question, to make clear, that I speak about third party libraries. I think this is an important information I did not mention originally.

Comment: @HansPassant: I do this only for third party libraries. Not for my own projects. I updated my original question.